# How does Apple One consolidate family member free trial subscriptions?

Tags: icloud, apple-music, apple-news, fitness+, apple-arcade

I've been wanting to start an Apple One family subscription for a little while, just to consolidate all of the charges my partner and I are paying for (it's borderline whether it represents good value for us as we won't use all of the features).

But between us we keep getting free trials for Apple TV/News and other offers that mean it doesn't quite make sense to start.

My question is: If we start an Apple One subscription, does it somehow take into account free trials? Can you still take advantage of future free trial offers?

Comment: I believe that free trials are specifically for people who don't already have an Apple [One] subscription. I tried this shortly after I got an Apple TV+ subscription, like the DAY after. The Apple rep on the phone was polite but kept saying no. Eventually I got her to add a free month onto my subscription. But like every other company that offers subscriptions, "free" months are only for those who don't **already** subscribe.